# GLKView + CIImage with Alpha + AVFoundation = Trippy Mess

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-image, glkit

I'm using AVFoundation to capture information from the camera, passing it to CIFilter to replace darker pixels with pixels with an alpha level of 0 and displaying it on a GLKView.

The containing view controller is a GLKViewController but the meat of the program starts with the function:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    @autoreleasepool {

        CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

                CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:(id)kCFNull forKey:kCIImageColorSpace]];


        image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2.0)];

        CGPoint origin = [image extent].origin;
        image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-origin.x, -origin.y)];

        [self.replaceDarkColorWithTransparentFilter setValue:image forKey:@"inputImage"];

        image = self.replaceDarkColorWithTransparentFilter.outputImage;

        [self.ciContext drawImage:image inRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, 640.0f) fromRect:[image extent]];
        [self.eaglContext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];

        [self.replaceDarkColorWithTransparentFilter setValue:nil forKey:@"inputImage"];
    }
}
```

In the GLKViewController, I initialize the render buffer using:

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_renderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderBuffer);
```

The result is that older images are not being cleared and showing through. The result looks like this: http://d.pr/i/M02z Is this normal? Shouldn't it be clearing out the old context and starting fresh?

I've tried `glFlush();` at update and `glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect` and trying to draw nil for the Image in the CIContext to no avail.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to clear out the previous contents of your framebuffer using code like

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

at some point before you draw the new Core Image frame. This will set the contents and alpha channel of the framebuffer to 0.0 to give you a clean slate on which to draw your filtered image.

You might also need to set the current OpenGL ES context using something like

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.openGLESContext];
```

right before that, because I can't remember if Core Image will leave that set properly for whatever thread you're working on.

Comment: Thanks Brad, 

Unfortunately, that causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS as I don't think I have rights to the GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT when using a GLKView. I was able to resolve it, in a way, by drawing a blank CIImage to the CIContext before I draw the filtered image. 

Also, I did set the EAGLContext when I set up the view, but good thinking!

I'll mark it as answered but want to see if others can chime in first. 

Thanks again!

Comment: @Jacob - Odd that you can't clear the color bit on a GLKView. You should be able to do that. Did you try setting the current context to your OpenGL ES context before you did this? The only times you should see a bad access with something like this would be if you were trying to simultaneously access the OpenGL ES context from two different threads.

Comment: I did set the EAGLContext before and it made no difference…

It still caused a EXC_BAD_ACCESS which might be a result of two different threads accessing the EAGLContext but I don't handle that explicitly.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: Jacob is right, for some reason the GLKView doesn't like an empty frame. So you have to draw something even if it's transparent.